# Why I cant add "enter" in jquery file

Tags: jquery

I don't know a lot about `jquery`. I downloaded a website that has a `jquery` file. but the code in all `.js` files(`jquery`,`js`) hasn't any new line.

I wanted to explore the code, so I replace all `;` with `;\n` and all `}` with `}\n` .

but when I saved the code, they didn't run.

Why is that? and how can I make `.js` files more readable?

Comment: Did you removed the `\n` and what error are you getting? Adding "enter" in `js` file should not cause a problem.

Comment: It depends. For example adding enter in regular expression can certainly breake code. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You downloaded minified version. You simply need development one.

Minified versions usually have `.min.js` at the end. All unnecessary spaces and line breaks are removed from them.

Look for word 'development' at http://jquery.com/download/.

Comment: What is the difference between minified and development versions?

Comment: @YazanWYusuf: The difference is purely one of readability.  The behavior of the code is identical.  Minified versions are simply much smaller and optimized for network transfer rather than for human readability.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf I explained that in update. All unnecessary spaces and line breaks are removed from them, variable names made shortest. It is all for reducing size.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found a [decompressor](http://html-generator.weebly.com/javascript-decompressor.html) for jquery codes and that worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

It is [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). Such file weight much less and this is important in web.

You can find decompressed source code on [jQuery webside](http://jquery.com/download/).

[Direct link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js)